# http.post() method Bad request issue

Tags: angular, post

I am creating access token for SalesForce api and when I send requests through http.post() I am getting error like Bad Requests 400.
Here is my code:

```
getToken():Observable<any[]>{
       this.body={grant_type:'password',client_id:'3MVG9d8..57qfn8zsI8Du1zalkfIOVSz0qw_6Way_SrP6fP1apM3Pges9bhahYwdg.',client_secret:'5035130443686',username:'user@demo.com',password:'blabla'};
this.body2=JSON.stringify(this.body);
 let headers = new Headers({"Content-Type": "application/json"});
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers});

       this.authorization = this.http.post("https://demo-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token",this.body2,options)
       .map((res:any) => res.json());

       return this.authorization;


    }
```

But the below code works perfectly:

```
getToken():Observable<any[]>{

      var body="grant_type=password&client_id=3MVG9d8..z.Sz0qw_6Way_SrP6fP1apM3Pges9bhahYwdg.&client_secret=50351305443686&username=user@demo.com&password=blabla";

 let headers = new Headers({"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"});

        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers});

       this.authorization = this.http.post("https://demo-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token",this.body,options)
       .map((res:any) => res.json());

       return this.authorization;

    }
```

But I want to run the first part of code.Don't what is the issue!

Answer (score 2):

try to run your first code without using `JSON.stringify(this.body);`
send this.body directly to the post method.

Answer (score 1):

JSON.stringify doesn't convert params object to the right format. You need to use custom function. See [the working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ebi5oi3vk9iHAhBflIKu?p=preview). It returns `invalid_client_id`, change credentials.

```
  getToken():Observable<any[]>{
    const body = {grant_type:'password',client_id:'3MVG9d8..57qfn8zsI8Du1zalkfIOVSz0qw_6Way_SrP6fP1apM3Pges9bhahYwdg.',client_secret:'5035130443686',username:'user@demo.com',password:'blabla'};
    const bodyStr = this.buildString(body);
    let headers = new Headers({"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"});

    this.authorization = this.http.post("https://demo-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token", bodyStr, { headers: headers })
     .map((res:any) => res.json());

     return this.authorization;

  }

  buildString(obj) {
    var str = [];
    for(var p in obj)
      str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
    return str.join("&");
  }
```